# Training on a video dataset?

Tags: video, dataset

I am using the Standford Drone Dataset which is made up of videos that are annotated and I am training to figure out how to train on this. Can you just train on the videos? I assume you have to cut up the video into frames and if so does anyone know of an example to automate that?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to extract the video frames for training purpose.

```
import cv2
video = cv2.VideoCapture(path) 
success = 1  
while success: 
    success, image = video.read() 
    #Here you can either save the frame or directly use it in training.
    cv2.imwrite("frame.png",image) #This will save the image/frame to file named frma.png
```

As shown in above code, you can either save the frames one by one to your training data folder or can just provide it as input to your CNN (Will save time as well as memory to save the files).

Also you can have a look on python's opencv library.

Comment: Thank you for the response. My concern is making sure the frames that are extracted match the annotations or will that be a nonissue since OpenCV will just be separating the frames that make up the video?

Comment: I don't think there will be any issue for training dataset.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but I did do what was suggested although I used a tool to do it. I am now writing a tool to cut up the large images and keep the bounding boxes. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How big is your dataset? Depending on this, I'm not sure whether Jaydip's answer makes sense given how long it'll take to just convert to frames. I found no good tools out there so I've been building an API called [Sieve](https://sievedata.com/). It basically takes all your raw video data and makes it searchable by things like motion, objects, etc so you can export the exact frames you want from any raw video.

Though you can't upload your specific annotations with the video, we let you download metadata which gives you the frame number, video name, and more information that can help you associate your existing annotations to the frames.

Take a look at this repo: https://github.com/Sieve-Data/automatic-video-processing. More specifically, you can look at the `sieve_helpers.py` file if you'd like to upload a local video.